# Is laravel created_at and updated_at inverse?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Laravel Framework version 5.2.5

When I updated a record, update_at was not changed but created_at changed to the current timestamp.

Is this correct?

```
MariaDB [moon]> show columns from users;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| name           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| email          | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                             |
| password       | varchar(60)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| remember_token | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| created_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| updated_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds strange.

Comment: Please post your model and the code that is causing the inverted change.

Comment: Obviously it's incorrect (same as in question duplicated) - you shouldn't have `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `created_at` column

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Thank you. Seems it's because of mariadb's version cause the fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your database structure the problem is `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `created_at` column. It shouldn't be obviously like this. Looking at migrations it's unlikely this migration set automatically this, so probably it has been set manually in MySQL, so you should remove `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `created_at` column.

When you update your model using Eloquent `updated_at` column should be updated without a problem (also in current database schema) - if it's not you probably don't use Eloquent, so it won't be updated automatically. If you are not sure, please show your code how you update this record

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems because of mysql's default behavior. [THIS ISSUE](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1260) And I'm trying to give a default value to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people have had this issue recently, and you can read the discussion on Github here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11518

> MySQL 5.7 no longer allows 0000-00-00 as a valid timestamp with
> strict mode turned on (which it is by default). So either use
> `->nullableTimestamps()` or `->timestamp()->useCurrent()`.

You can fix this by changing this:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

To either one of these options:

```
// Option 1:
$table->nullableTimestamps();

// Option 2:
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

Also, on this MySQL page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

> Alternatively, if `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` is disabled (the default), do either of the following:
>
> Define the column with a DEFAULT clause that specifies a constant default value.
>
> Specify the NULL attribute. This also causes the column to permit NULL values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp by setting the column to NULL. Assigning NULL sets the column to NULL.

In either case, the above solution should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the Blueprint and fixed this :)

Answer (score 0):

hi guys my name is arash laghaei from iran
i fix this problem
please do it:
vendor/laravel/framework/srs/illuminate/database/schema/blueprint.php
line:792

```
 public function timestamps()
{
    $this->timestamp('updated_at');

    $this->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

}
```

please do it exactly i write.
and fixed this problem.

Comment: Thank you.
And seems laravel has fixed it by append '->nullable()' now. :)